# VSCode and clang-format: use my own file extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

I use Visual Studio Code with clang-format extension to format .c source code files - it works.

Now I have special files (C-style, also) but that files are not recognized for formatting since they have another file extension (.kki).

How can I configure the clang-format extension within Visual Studio Code to recognize my `.kki` files as C-source code files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you can follow the "[Adding a file extension to a language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language)" section:

> You can add new file extensions to an existing language with the **`files.associations`** setting.
>
> For example, the setting below adds the .myphp file extension to the php language identifier:
>
> ```
> "files.associations": {
>     "*.myphp": "php"
> }
> ```
>
> IntelliSense (Ctrl+Space) will show you the available language identifiers.

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/languages/overview/language-id-intellisense.png]

In your case:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.kki": "c"
}
```