# Visual Studio Code - .clang-format *.C files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang-format

How do I setup `clang-format` to grab `*.c` files on save in VS Code, using "Microsoft C/C++ Extension"?

I want the formatting to automatically happen when I press `Ctrl+S`. Formatting of `*.cpp` files works fine.

[Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977305/vscode-and-clang-format-use-my-own-file-extension) I figured out is to add a file association in my `settings.json` file, making C files pretend to be C++.

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.c": "cpp",
    ...
}
```

I am not sure, however, what does this break in the background...

Thanks

Comment: Have you already read this:https://eellaup.medium.com/how-to-set-up-clang-format-in-visual-studio-code-in-a-vagrant-environment-georgiatech-gios-1935ed73efd1 ?

Comment: @Bob__ yes I did, he uses the "clang-format Extension"